# Python text for loop list index out of range

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a code that prints hello and a different number on each line. Sample output would look like this:

hi 21

hi 22

hi 23

etc. However I am getting a list index out of range error for my for loop.

Here is my code:

```
    number = [21,22,23]
    for x in number:
        print('hi',number[x],'\n')
```

I am new to programming and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Change your print call to: `print('hi', x)`

Comment: Thanks!! That did it

Comment: The first time through your loop `x` will be `21`, the second time `22` and so forth.  When you try to access `number[x]`, you're really accessing `number[21]`.  As `number` isn't long enough to have an index `21`, you're getting this error.